# bottomsheet stops between EXPANDED and HIDDEN

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

I'm trying to create a bottomsheet that's either completely expanded or completely out of view - I don't want it to be anywhere in the middle or peeking.

Here's the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_skipCollapsed="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/cinza3"
            android:text="clear/delete Q"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my code I have the following methods:

```
private void showHideBottomSheet() {
        if (mBSBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
            showBottomSheet();
        } else {
            hideBottomSheet();
        }
    }


    private void showBottomSheet() {
        mBSBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    }


    private void hideBottomSheet() {
        mBSBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    }
```

And in my layout there's a button that calls showHideBottomSheet() when clicked.

When I click the button, everything works fine and the bottomsheet is shown/hidden. But if it's EXPANDED and I click on a textview elsewhere in the code (outside the bottomsheet), for example, the bottomsheet moves down a little, but not completely - it's top half is visible, but if I log it's state, it's STATE_EXPANDED.

1. what's the difference between STATE_HIDDEN and STATE_COLLAPSED? I've searched everywhere for a visual explanation but couldn't find it. Is this 'intermediate' state the collapsed state? Even if I set peekHeight="0" in the xml and skipCollapsed="true"?
2. what does peekHeight and skipCollapsed in the xml actually do?
3. how can I make it to be fully visible or fully hidden at all times and avoid this 'intermediate' state?

EDIT: There's a TextView inside the BottomSheet, and and OnClickListener on it. When I click it, the BottomSheet goes to that 'intermediate' state too, even though the OnclickListener does not call setState or anything related to the BottomSheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated my support:design library to 25.3.1 and it started working as expected.

Comment: I think this was also reason of your issue, you have height and width of your `LinearLayout` `android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"`